# iOS10: Hide status bar when using a UITabBarController()

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, ios10, statusbar

I have a `UITabBarController()` that I use and assign in `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    showTabBar()
    return true
}

func showTabBar() {
    let tabBarVC = TabBarVC()
    if let window = self.window {
        window.rootViewController = tabBarVC
    }
}
```

I have the following key is in `info.plist`:

[image]

In my `Target` under `General`, I have the following setting:

[image]

I use the following code in one of my tabs to hide the Status Bar:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var statusBarShouldBeHidden = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return statusBarShouldBeHidden
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return .slide
    }


    @IBAction func buttonHideShowStatusBarTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        statusBarShouldBeHidden  = !statusBarShouldBeHidden

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            print("animating")
        }
    }
}
```

When the button is tapped, "animating" prints in the log; however, the status bar does not hide.

I am not sure if this is related to `UITabBarController()`, but the code above seems to work fine in a project without it.

How can I hide the status bar in iOS10 when using `UITabBarController()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have taken TabBarVC as `UIViewController` subclass rather than `UITabBarController` subclass and then initialised and added the `UITabBarController` instance to it's view, I think TabBarVC should be subclass of `UITabBarController` and should be the rootViewController of the window. If you change the TabBarVC to subclass of `UITabbarViewController` status bar is working fine. Check the code below

```
class TabBarVC: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    //var mainTabBarController = UITabBarController() //not needed

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
        self.selectedIndex = 0
        self.customizableViewControllers = []
        self.setViewControllers(self.topLevelControllers(), animated: false)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` in your root view controller, i.e. `TabBarVC`. Here is the solution:

Override `prefersStatusBarHidden` in `TabBarVC` to return value of `selectedViewController`

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return mainTabBarController.selectedViewController?.prefersStatusBarHidden ?? false
}
```

Add reference to `TabBarVC` in `ViewController` class

```
var tabBarVC: UIViewController?
```

Set `tabBarVC` variable on `topLevelControllers()` method

```
let one = self.viewControllerFromStoryBoard(storyboardName: "One",
                                                  sceneName: "Initial",
                                                  iconName: "",
                                                  title: "Tab One") as! ViewController
one.tabBarVC = self
```

Finally, on your @IBAction update your status bar

```
self.tabBarVC?.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```